# Как из AlertDialog вызвать основную активити

Tags: java, android

Моё свёрнутое приложение вызывает `AlertDialog`. В нём две кнопки: *ОК* и *Cancel*.
По *Cancel* просто закрываем `AlertDialog`, а вот по кнопке *OK* нужно отобразить основное активити приложения или просто вывести приложение на передний план.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обработчике нажатия кнопки *OK* создайте `Intent` с запуском Вашей `Activity` и флагом `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` или `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, в зависимости от необходимого поведения:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Допустим, я отобразил одно активити на переднем плане. Если из него я перейду в другое активити, оно тоже будет на переднем плане?

Comment: @sitev_ru На переднем плане может быть только одна активити - последняя вызванная. Те, что были до нее уходят в фон и заносятся в стек переходов. `SINGLE_TOP` - выводит активити на вершине стека из свернутого состояния без создания нового экземпляра (просто "поднимает" ее). `CLEAR_TOP` - делает то же самое, но для активити не на вершине стека, заодно уничтожая стек перед ней - (переводит на вершину стека)/ Можете [почитать](http://habrahabr.ru/post/186434/) по стеку активити

Comment: Ещё раз попорядку: свернул приложение, вызвал AlertDialog, из него вызвал активити1, из активити1 вызываю активити2... Так вот это активити2 точно отобразится на экране телефона?

Comment: @sitev_ru конечно, откуда сомнения?

Comment: А можно сразу из моего свёрнутого приложения (а в это время поверх запущено другое приложение) вывести активити моего приложения без AlertDialog?

Comment: Можно. Запустите Activity из Service кодом, аналогичным приведенному в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Сейчас уже не смогу, вечером потестирую - сообщу, что у меня получилось/неполучилось в итоге..