# Как открыть развернуть активити из диалога(или сервиса например)

Tags: android, activity

У меня есть диалог с такими настройками:

```
getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

Это значит что он может открываться вне активити, например из сервиса. у меня для этого дает команду сервер. В общем открывается он классно. Но в диалоге есть кнопка "Принять" при нажатии на которую мне нужно открыть мою программу, которая в этот момент свернута. Я нашел такое решение:

```
if (AppContext.PAUSE_NOW) {
                        Intent startActivity = new Intent();
                        startActivity.setClass(mContext, SeDiDriverClient.class);
                        startActivity.setAction(SeDiDriverClient.class.getName());
                        startActivity.setFlags(
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                        mContext.startActivity(startActivity);
                    }
```

И оно работает. Но приусловии что в этот момент не открыты другие программы. Например все свернуто и я нажимаю принять - открывается моя прога. Но если я например в браузере или любой другой программе, то диалог также открывается поверх нее, но на нажатие "принять" ничего не происходит. как это исправить кто может знать?

Я перепробовал разные флаги, но работает. Просто открывается приложение которое было открыто последним

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как из AlertDialog вызвать основную активити](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445186/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-alertdialog-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8)

Comment: Что такое `AppContext.PAUSE_NOW` в Вашем коде? Вы убедились, что фактически `startActivity` выполняется в обоих случаях?

Comment: да дубликат, но решение из старого вопроса не работает у меня((((

Comment: AppContext.PAUSE_NOW значит что активити свернуто. все выполняется. проблема только если уже чтото другое открыто

Comment: В общем он просто открывает последнее приложение, которое было открыто, если все свернуто, и ничего не открывает если чтото открыто

Comment: @ip696: расскажите, как вы использовали решение из старого вопроса и что при этом не получилось?